# Can less load lines which were appended to a file after opening?

Tags: logs, tail, less

When I am viewing a log file in `less` is it possible to make less reload the file to get lines which were appended to that file since it was opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (for “**f**ollow”, like in `tail -f`). This will start the continuous output. You can exit the continuous output display with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and refine or cancel your filter pattern or start a search.

From [man less](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=less&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en):

> `F`
>    Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file  is
>   reached.   Normally  this  command would be used when already at
>   the end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a  file
>   which  is  growing  while  it is being viewed.  (The behavior is
>   similar to the "tail -f" command.)

Answer (score 3):

When you have opened a text file in Less, by pressing **F** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), you can change to follow mode. Less will then wait for new data.  You can also use `less +F` to start Less in follow mode.